# Searching a directory for folders and files using python

Tags: python, path, operating-system, directory

I have a directory structure like the one given below.

```
         MainFolder 
             |
           [lib] 
         /   |   \
       [A]  [B]  [C] -- file1.so 
        |     |         file2.so
   file1.so   file1.so
   file2.so   file2.so
```

I'm trying to look for the 'lib' folder in that structure which might not be there at times. So I'm using the following to check for the presence of the 'lib' folder:

```
   if os.path.isdir(apkLocation + apkFolder + '/lib/'):
```

If lib folder exists, then I carry on to search the folders  inside 'lib'. I have to store the names of the folder A,B and C and look for the files ending with '.so' whose path should be stored as /lib/A/file1.so,/lib/A/file2.so and so on.

```
 if os.path.isdir(apkLocation + apkFolder + '/lib/'):
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(apkLocation + apkFolder):
            for name in files:
                if name.endswith(("lib", ".so")):
                    print os.path.abspath(name)
```

This gives me an out

```
                  file1.so
                  file2.so
                  file1.so
                  file2.so
                  file1.so
                  file2.so
```

Desired output:

```
           /lib/A/file1.so
           /lib/A/file2.so
           /lib/B/file1.so
           /lib/B/file2.so
           /lib/C/file1.so
           /lib/C/file2.so
```

and also the folders A,B and C are to be saved separately.

Comment: `apkLocation + apkFolder + '/lib/'` - Don't add path segments - use `os.path.join(apkLocation, apkFolder, 'lib')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to join the current directory and the name to get the absolute path to a file:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(apkLocation + apkFolder):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(("lib", ".so")):
            os.path.join(root, name)
```

It's documented here http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk, too.

Comment: That worked :) How do I retrieve the folder A,B and C instead of playing around with string functions on the output of os.path.join(root,name)? Any path functions that does this?

Comment: This did it os.path.join(root,name).replace(apkLocation+apkFolder+'/lib','')

Comment: You are looking for os.path.split() and maybe os.path.dirname(). It's all well documented, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join at first the current directory and the filename to get the whole path to the file:
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(apkLocation + apkFolder):
for name in files:
if name.endswith(("lib", ".so")):
os.path.join(root, name)